# Can call headless from cmd but not from powershell

Tags: powershell, google-chrome

In dos when I paste this command it works:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" https://google.com --screenshot=c:\test\google.png --headless --hide-scrollbars --window-size=1920,1080 --disable-gpu &
```

When I do the same in Powershell it doesn't. I guess my syntax not right ?

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn't"? A little more input whould be nice...

Comment: Do you get any feedback at all in the powershell prompt?  Any errors etc?

Comment: The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. Probably

Comment: IIRC Powershell treats `--` as its own switches, not your command's. Add `--` as the first parameter after the exe. And probably escape the comma as `\`,`

Comment: [The Windows command prompt is NOT a DOS prompt!](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `Start-Process` in Powershell and parse the Arguments:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -ArgumentList "https://google.com","--screenshot=c:\test\google.png","--headless","--hide-scrollbars","--window-size=1920,1080","--disable-gpu"
```

Comment: `Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -ArgumentList "https://chromestatus.com","--headless","--disable-gpu",'--dump-dom'` will print nothing, got it from [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome).